# Using DataBase First Approach with EF in SharePoint?

Tags: database, linq

I have seen here and there that Entity framework and Linq works with SharePoint. But can we use Entity framework Database first approach in SharePoint?

http://cdn.rssbus.com/help/RS3/ado/pg_usingEFIntro.htm

Here they only highlights model and and code first. I suppose because they use SharePoint Lists. But i want to use an external database with EF so db first would suit me more as i don't want to migrate data from my external db to sharepoint lists.

Any links to tutorials or exiting technology is welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database first approach using EF with external database , the steps are more or less same as in any plain .NET project. You can look at below blogs:

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application

To get info about CRUD Operations:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/869553/CRUD-operation-with-Entity-Framework-Database-Fi

Edit:

1. Create a farm solution (since you want to deploy webparts).
2. Add new project and add the EF component in this project.
3. In the main project , you can add webpart and that webpart can use your EF entities for CRUD operations.

Comment: Yes you can add new project into your solution and that project will implement EF component. In your main project , webparts can access the EF classes to do CRUD

Comment: So i can make a webPart that uses EF database first and hten deploy it on sharepoint all that with my external to SharePoint database?

Comment: See my edited answer